# How to trace high CPU usage in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, ssh, whm

Recently, I have an issue with my website from around 6pm gmt and 4am gmt.

I thought at first it was due to visitors at high traffic time but from 0am to 4am I have less visitors than times where the problem doesn't occur. My server gets high CPU usage. Here's the top command screenshot.

[image]

I have a dedicated server with 8 cores and 8 GB memory.

Comment: It's entirely unclear how anybody could help with the information provided. It's a list of processes. Looks like the issue is MySQL. Dunno what else you think anybody could tell you.

Comment: What could it be happening in my sql database?

Comment: @AnasZine Run `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in MySQL and find out.

Comment: Turn on your slow queries log and find out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide more infos about your issues. That's just a print screen and it's pretty hard to deduct anything based only on that! Check your apache server logs for that specific cPanel user (`/usr/local/apache/domlogs/cpanel_user/domain.tld` - that's the apache access log file for that account), run as suggested by others `SHOW PROCESSLIST` in mysql or install a tool like `mytop` or mtop